# Jersey ServletContainer Hangs when logging errors in Errors.logErrors

Tags: java, rest, jersey

We are facing a severe problem where our Jersey container going into hang state, when we reload the resourceConfig. 
Code which reloads jersey container is 
container.reload(ResourceConfig.forApplication(application));

We are not able to find out root cause for this issue and it is now blocking our release.

We are using jersey version 2.13.

The stack trace we receive is as follows

```
Thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] (Suspended)  
owns: BufferedOutputStream  (id=3280)   
owns: PrintStream  (id=3281)    
owns: LoggingConfigurationHelper$2  (id=3282)   
owns: OutputStreamWriter  (id=3283) 
owns: ConsoleHandler  (id=3284) 
owns: RestfulConnector  (id=2845)   
FileOutputStream.writeBytes(byte[], int, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
FileOutputStream.write(byte[], int, int) line: not available    
BufferedOutputStream.write(byte[], int, int) line: not available    
PrintStream.write(byte[], int, int) line: not available 
LoggingConfigurationHelper$2(PrintStream).write(byte[], int, int) line: not available   
StreamEncoder.writeBytes() line: not available  
StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer() line: not available 
StreamEncoder.implFlush() line: not available   
StreamEncoder.flush() line: not available   
OutputStreamWriter.flush() line: not available  
ConsoleHandler(StreamHandler).flush() line: not available   
ConsoleHandler.publish(LogRecord) line: not available   
Logger.log(LogRecord) line: not available   
Logger.doLog(LogRecord) line: not available 
Logger.log(Level, String) line: not available   
Logger.warning(String) line: not available  
Errors.logErrors(Collection<ErrorMessage>) line: 191    
Errors.processErrors(boolean) line: 132 
Errors.postProcess(boolean) line: 423   
Errors.process(Callable<T>, boolean) line: 320  
Errors.process(Producer<T>, boolean) line: 297  
Errors.processWithException(Runnable) line: 286 
ApplicationHandler.<init>(Application, Binder, ServiceLocator) line: 320    
ApplicationHandler.<init>(Application, Binder) line: 285    
WebComponent.<init>(WebConfig, ResourceConfig) line: 311    
ServletContainer.reload(ResourceConfig) line: 578
```

We have one suspect as well. In one of our REST resource, we are returning List. We observed following warning in jersey logs, after this log the container goes into unusable state.

```
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: 
WARNING: Return type, java.util.List<SomeObject>, of method, public java.util.List<SomeObject> myResource.get(javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,java.lang.String,java.lang.String), is not resolvable to a concrete type.
```

Any help will be a great help!
Kindly let me know if you need more information.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could address this issue by configuring the logging. Now, the logs are directed to files.